# Does requestLocationUpdates() create a sperate service?

Tags: android, android-service, location-client

In my application I am using .requestLocationUpdates() method of the LocationClient Class to request for location every 5 seconds. Once a location update is received it will call onLocationChanged method in which I am creating a new AsyncTask to upload the location data to a web server.

The problem is I am doing all this in the main UI thread, so the upload stops when app pauses. I am thinking to request for location updates in a new service, but I have a doubt in mind :

**Does .requestLocationUpdates() methods creates its own service ? Do I really need to create a service myself or .requestLocationUpdates() method will do it for me ?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep running your ".requestLocationUpdates()" when the app is paused, you have to use a Service with "START_STICKY" flag. 
And I think yes, ".requestLocationUpdate()" methods creates its own service or its own thread, but you don't have any access to this.